# How to draw to front buffer with QOpenGLWidget

Tags: opengl, qt5

I am upgrading my application from QGLWidget using Qt 5.3.2 to QOpenGLWidget using QT 5.6.0. The application is upgraded and runs well. However, I am stuck trying to preserve my debugging tools. My development environment is Visual Studio 2013 and even though the final application is using double buffered graphics, for debugging purposes I've written some methods that I could invoke interactively from the debugger, draw into front buffer and see the output on the screen. These functions no longer work because QOpenGLWidget draws to frame buffer. Furthermore, even before attempting to draw when I call glDrawBuffer(GL_FRONT) it generates glError to 1280 (invalid enum). Additional piece of data - glGetIntegerv(GL_DRAW_BUFFER, &my_val) returns 0x8ce0 which is GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 and would make sense with GL 3.0 even though my intent was to limit GL features to 2.0 only.

Comment: QOpenGLWidget draws to an intermediate FBO, hence it requires OpenGL 3 / OpenGL 2 + FBO / OpenGL ES 2, and doesn't offer access to the `GL_FRONT` draw buffer. If you *really* need that, use `QOpenGLWindow` + `createWindowContainer` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It sounds like it would involve quite a bit of work.

Comment: @peppe 's suggestion turned out to work (mostly) nicely. There is still an issue of keyboard focus though that I am not sure how to overcome. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37196155/how-to-direct-keyboard-input-qopenglwindow-in-5-6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit for the solution goes to @peppe. His suggestion turned out to be not too difficult to implement and allowed me to achieve what I wanted. Switching from QOpenGLWidget to a combination of QOpenGLWindows and its QWidget container allowed me to achieve exactly what I wanted.

I derived my class from QOpenGLWindow and had it remember a pointer to a QWidget obtained via QWidget::createWindowContainer(my_class_pointer); Then, whenever I used to take advantage of QGLWidget methods that aren't present in QOpenGLWidget I redirected these calls to the container.

QOpenGLWindow seems to be perfectly content with my debugging tools drawing directly into front buffer.